# Enable save button using shouldChangeTextInRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to create a save button which becomes enabled when the user enters text into both a `TextView` and a `TextField`.

I have a `IBOutlet` called 'saveButton' created for the button.

With the following code, the save button never becomes enabled.

```
- (void) enableSaveButtonForQuote: (NSString *) quoteText author: (NSString *) authorText {

self.saveButton.enabled = (quoteText.length > 0 && authorText > 0);
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:
(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
   NSString *changedString = [textView.testringByReplacingCharactersInRange:
range withString: text];

[self enableSaveButtonForQuote: changedString author: 
self.authorTextField.text];    
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:
(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *changedString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:
range withString: string];

[self enableSaveButtonForQuote:self.quoteTextView.text author:changedString];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are the `UITextViewDelegate` or `UITextFieldDelegate` methods ever being called?

Comment: Yes, they are - both delegates are declared in the header file

Comment: Is the `enableSaveButtonForQuote:author:` method ever being called?

Comment: y dont u do simply enable=yes in shouldchangechatracters method

Comment: Use the debugger. Verify all of the methods you expect to be called are actually being called. Verify the various values have the value you expect them to have. Then update your question with relevant details. No one can answer your question since you haven't told us what is actually happening with the posted code.

Comment: enableSaveButtonForQuote:author gets called in the delegate mehods

Comment: OK, and then what? Have you verified that `self.saveButton` isn't `nil`? Have you checked the values for `quoteText` and `authorText`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use bool value to make this happen

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:
(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
   //lets say you enter text first into textview
 textViewBoolValue=YES;
  if(textViewBoolValue && textFieldBoolValue ){
          button.enabled=YES
   }   
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:
(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

 textFieldBoolValue=YES;

 if(textViewBoolValue && textFieldBoolValue ){
          button.enabled=YES
   }
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to check the length property of the authorText in the enableSaveButtonForQuote method.

Also make sure the delegates for the textField and textView are set.

Also, you do not need to initialize another string object within each delegate method. You already have a reference to the textfield / textView through class variables. You should just use the text from those.

Comment: Ok, the delegate for both IBOutlets is set to the viewController that the that the textField and textView are contained in, but it's still not working...

Comment: @Alexander Yes, you do need to initialize the strings in the delegate methods. How else are you going to determine what the changed text will be when `YES` is returned from the `shouldChangeText` method?

Comment: @rmaddy sorry I forgot that the text property changes after the delegate method returns true.